# eclipse cause Lint error when save any layout xml files

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-lint

I think I'd tried everything to fix it but failed.

I've downloaded eclipse from here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neonr

It's the latest eclipse package made to work with android app developing.

AND

I've downloaded and installed Android Sdk from:

https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe

https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip

That's right, both windows and mac versions.

My Android sdk looks like this.

[image: android sdk screenshot]

And I created a new android application project, and I just open a pre-made layout xml file and as soon as I save a change I got this.

```
'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem.
Failed
Detail:
Failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

[image: Android Lint error]

So, here is the big question, how to fix android lint? Or at least point me the right direction, I've tried this on a PC and on a Mac, same problem.

Update: I know android studio and I've used it alot. Let's just say I have my reasons to pick up eclipse and make it work again.

Comment: Dude, this is era of Android studio, why you are using eclipse still now?.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but, I had reasons. I was switched to android studio in 2012 and used ti ever since. And this eclipse thing is a nightmare to pick up...

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by turn off lint error check.

Click Window in Eclipse, select Preferences. Select Android -> Lint Error Checking on the left, and uncheck following checkboxes:
1.Run full error check when exporting app and abort if errors are found  2.When saving file check for error

For ref please check the screenshot I have attached: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I suppose I can always turn off lint but I'm still looking for an answer that leads to a root cause of this. I need to know why and if that reason is good enough, turning it off is acceptable. But I need to know why first. And if it's possible, I prefer a solution that doesn't turn lint off. Lint helps, it makes my work easier.